# Matrix factorization with a semi-orthogonality constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, orthogonal-matrices

Given $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, I have an optimization problem with an orthogonality constraint:

$$\min_{_{P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}, L \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}}}\left \| X - PL \right \|_{F}^{2} \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \:P^{T}P=I_{k} \tag{1}$$

I have tried to solve problem (1) by alternating between solving problem (2) and problem (3) as follows.

### Solving P:

$$\min_{_{P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}}}(\left \| X - PL \right \|_{F}^{2})  \quad \text{s.t.} \quad  \:P^{T}P=I_{k} \tag{2}$$

Problem (2) is the Orthogonal Procrustes problem.

By applying compact SVD on $XL^{T}$, we obtain:
$XL^{T}=U\Sigma V^{T}$ where $U$ is of size $n$ by $k$, $\Sigma$ is of size $k$ by $k$, and $V$ is of size $k$ by $k$.
Then the solution to problem (2) is :

$P=UV^{T}$.

### Solving L:

$$\min_{_{L \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}}}(\left \| X - PL \right \|_{F}^{2}) \quad \text{s.t.} \quad P^{T}P=I_{k} \tag{3}$$

Solution of problem (3) is straightforward:

$L = P^{T}X$

### Question

My optimizer always converges at a local minimum. Is there another way to solve problem (1) ?

Comment: Orthogonal? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-orthogonal_matrix

Comment: Yes, you are right. P is rather semi-orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is another way. Note that with the existence of the [rank-revealing $QR$ factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRQR_factorization), we find that a matrix $M$ can be written in the form $M = PL$ with $P$ of size $n \times k$, $L$ of size $k \times d$, and $P^TP = I$
if and only if $M$ has rank at most $k$. With that, we can equivalently frame problem (1) as
$$
\min_{M}\|X - M\|_F \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \operatorname{rank}(M) \leq k. \tag{0}
$$
In other words, this is simply a [low-rank approximation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation). As is explained in the linked page, the EYM theorem guarantees that the minimizer $M_*$ can be obtained from the truncated SVD of $X$. That is, let
$$
X = U\Sigma V^{\top} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}
$$
be a [thin singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Thin_SVD) of $X$ and partition $U$, $\Sigma=:\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_{\min\{n,d\}})$, and $V$ as follows:
$$
U =: \begin{bmatrix} U_1 & U_2\end{bmatrix}, \quad 
\Sigma =: \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \Sigma_2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad\text{and}\quad 
V =: \begin{bmatrix} V_1 & V_2 \end{bmatrix},
$$
where $U_1$ is $n\times k$, $\Sigma_1$ is $k\times k$, and $V_1$ is $d\times k$. Then the rank-$k$ matrix, obtained from the truncated singular value decomposition
$$
M_* = U_1 \Sigma_1 V_1^{\top},
$$
minimizes the objective function for (0). If we take $P = U_1$ and $L = \Sigma_1V_1^\top$, then we find that $P$ and $L$ satisfy the required constraints.